# Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have created a validator for my UpdateView but I got this error (in title).

These are my codes.

**Forms.py**

```
class HotelBookingAdForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = HotelBookingAd
    fields = '__all__'

def clean_sales_price(self):
    sales_price = self.cleaned_data["sales_price"]
    if sales_price > purchase_price:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Error")
        print("error")

    return sales_price
```

**Views.py**

```
class HotelUpdate(AuthorsAccessMixin,FieldsMixin,FormValidMixin,UpdateView):
    model = HotelBookingAd
    form_class = HotelBookingAdForm
    template_name = "account/article-create-update.html"
```

**Models.py**

```
class HotelBookingAd(models.Model):
     purchase_price = models.IntegerField()
     sales_price = models.IntegerField()
```

after i try to reach HotelUpdate view i got the Error --> **Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted.** (in web browser).

also i have removed fields from HotelBookingAdForm and got this error in console :

*Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form HotelBookingAdForm needs updating.*

**Can anybody help me to fix this problem? Thanks!**

Comment: Do you really need all these Mixins in your view ? I am pretty sure taking off `FieldsMixin` solves your problem.

Comment: Wrote it as answer, do you mind validating it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, you were using additional unnecessary mixins.

You need to change it from:

`class HotelUpdate(AuthorsAccessMixin,FieldsMixin,FormValidMixin,UpdateView)`

To:

`class HotelUpdate(AuthorsAccessMixin,FormValidMixin,UpdateView)`

You probably can drop `FormValidMixin` too.